# Is there a way to get timeIntervalSince1970 without using NSDate?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdate

I'm trying to avoid creating an NSDate object since my code is heavy in needing the 'current time'.  I end up calling [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] a lot.  Is there any way to get the time interval without instantiating the object?

Comment: Can you possibly you C's time() function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent` gives you similar accuracy - no object required.

`CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent` uses a different base (or reference date), so you will have to initially determine the offset or the bases if you need to use another reference date (e.g. relative to some time in 1970).

Comment: This in combination with the NSTimeIntervalSince1970 constant will get the timeIntervalSince1970.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSTimeInterval interval = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

Comment: According to the Apple's documentation it is a class method in both iOS 2.0 or later and MacOS 10.0 or later.

Comment: This is still not quite as efficient as `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` because there's the (admittedly very small) overhead of a method dispatch.

Comment: @Rob Keniger While in principle I agree with you, optimizing at this level is nuts unless profiling reveals it to be necessary.  That being said, one can always cache the IMP and call it directly to stay with NS level APIs.

Answer (score 1):

you deleted your comment regarding an option with more accuracy than `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent`: try `gettimeofday`

Comment: It turns out CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent returns a double which has the decimal as the microseconds.

Comment: @David technically, `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent` has only *sub-second* accuracy. for example, the present time as `double` would lose few required digits required for usec accuracy. for microsecond accuracy, you'll have to use `gettimeofday` (or something similar). however it seems `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent` is suitable.

Comment: if you need usec accuracy and prefer to stick with CF-apis, `CFGregorian*` apis should work (they use structs for time representations).